# Creating CM-Wallpaper pattern using Inkscape's Tiled Clones tool

Tags: inkscape, tiles

I would like to recreate a relatively simple graphic pattern in Inkscape - dots arranged in a manner like in this image:

[image]

For what I have learned, this is [CM symmetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallpaper_group#Group_cm_(*%C3%97)) and fortunately, Inkscape's tiled clones tool has support for it. Unfortunately, I'm unable to get it working correctly.

It looks like Inkscape is creating two arrays of dots, one being slightly shifted (in X axis):

[image]

So far I was unable to influence that shift with any of the available settings. I can manually delete half of the clones and get what I want, but I believe there is a better solution.

EDIT:

I kind of managed to get what I want, but in order to do so I had to build a custom version of Inkscape. Editing the code responsible for clones' placement and tweaking in a bit kind of does the job - half of the clones are created in the original - place with this change, it's easy to delete them later with one click:

```cpp
//clonetiler.cpp
case TILE_CM:
    if ((i + j) % 2 == 0) {
        return Geom::Translate(0,0);
        //return d_s_r * rect_translate;
    } else {
        return d_s_r * flip_x * rect_translate;
    }
    break;
```

Result:

[image]

I'll keep the question open, as editing the Inkscape's code shouldn't be a part of regular workflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd make a gradient (in the picture it goes from transparent to black) and would use the 'trace background color' option to influence the size of the dots.

[image: trace background color in tiled clones dialog]

Now, in the above picture, the dots aren't shifted, but you can add that in the settings (Shift X per row 50%), screenshot:

[image: shift clones]

[image: better shift]

Comment: Now, in my picture, the dots aren't shifted, but you can add that in the settings (Shift X per row 50%), screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/KZ4RiuE.png

Comment: What kind of symmetry is that? P1 or CM? Because shifting the dots correctly is my main concern. I couldn't get this right no matter what I did.

Comment: It's P1 symmetry, the first and simplest.